# Windows 10 - works well but problems with any type of booting/rebooting

Tags: boot, windows-10

I have the strangest problem with Windows 10 and I haven't seen anyone online having the same problem with me.
Most people have similar issues while installing but in my case it installs and runs fine.

I formatted my drive and did a clean install few times and it always works well - it runs fast and looks stable - until the first reboot where it hangs at "Restarting..." or "Shutting down..." and after 20 minutes eventually gives the blue screen of death. After that point rebooting is no longer possible, only a format and clean install is possible or restoring to the original installation point.

I got Windows 10 running 6 times now from a fresh install and I tried everything. I mean EVERYTHING.

I tried disabling automatic updates and uninstalling all drivers in case one of those causes the problem - it failed.
I tried updating with all recommended windows 10 updates from DELL's support website - it failed.

I did manage to get a memory dump file, but it's 550Mb and I can't really email that to anyone nor do I understand what that data means.
The problem happens if I Restart, Shut down or Hibernate.
Sleep also hangs but when I sleep the screen goes black and remains black until I just force a shut down. So basically no booting options work.

Windows will work very well and fast without issues until it's time to use one of the dreaded booting options and then I have to format the drive and re-install.

If anyone has any clue what that is all about, please help!

Some system info:
DELL Inspiron 17R 5737 with Intel CPU i5 4th Gen.
DELL support site states laptop is Windows 10 ready and provides all Windows 10 compatible drivers. I checked and they are all automatically installed during setup. The system is stable at that point.

Comment: When I had this problem with my new build, the problem was caused by the GPU, I suspect your problems are caused by the iGPU and Intel's lack of full Windows 10 support.

Comment: I thought of that but most people with that problem have NVidia and I have Intel Graphics. Also on a clean install everything works fine so I don't see why booting or hibernating should have anything to do with it. 
Either way I tried various configurations. Firstly using the latest driver for Intel Graphics (says it's Win 10 ready), but I also tried reverting to the Microsoft standard display adapter. 
The problem kept occurring so I don't think it's anything to do with GPU

Comment: I literally told you that I had the same problem and it ended up being my display drivers.  Yes; I realize says the drivers are Windows 10 ready, except they are buggy, so its not all that ready and likely the source of your problems.

Comment: Okay so what's the solution? I explained that I tried uninstalling the GPU driver and it made no difference. Windows boots fine the first time after the installation so whatever driver it has after the setup seems to be okay.

Comment: You wait until the Intel's drivers are less buggy.  This behavior will continue even if you do a clean installation, being unable to reboot or hibernate, was the behavior I witness on my custom build.

Comment: Okay I am surprised they didn't sort that out in the final and official release. I guess I can play around with random drivers such as the Leshcat catalyst and if that doesn't work I will revert to 8.1

Comment: Intel was suppose to.  They didn't.  Microsoft has no control over Intel releasing quality working drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day working on this yesterday and I got my laptop being able to reboot for the very first time.

The problem is caused by the latest Intel Graphics driver which is automatically downloaded and installed by Windows Update. I now use the Catalyst Leshcat version which is 10.18.14.4222 and everything works well.

However it was extremely difficult to get this to work because Windows installs the driver during the "Set up" phase of Windows 10 Installation so to avoid getting it you have to turn internet off during installation and then when set up is complete set up your Internet as "metered" so no updates will be downloaded. This needs to be done super quickly because it will download and install it super quickly if you let it.

I am now doomed to have Updates switched off because I have done a few experiments and they all failed. One experiment was letting it install the drivers automatically and then forcing the old ones on top of the ones it installed for me, which didn't work. Also, for some reason, uninstalling the driver manually after it is installed will not prevent the problem. The only way is to not let it install at all.

Also the the "Show or hide updates" troubleshooter package called wushowhide.diagcab didn't work for me. I select the Graphics adapter driver and it says it is hidden but when I let windows run windows update, for some reason, the Graphic cards get installed and my computer gets ruined again. Is there some special trick to this tool or does it simply not always work?

I think my Dell computer was not ready for Windows 10 and I find it exasperating how little control we have over those "automatic updates" that force themselves on you, even when they just destroy the computer.

I am happy that my computer works now but Windows Updates will remain permanently switched off.

I hope this helps someone with the same Laptop as me